# What's the proper mathematical notation to say Range of Y in Domain of X

Tags: notation

How do I correctly express in mathematical notation with no words the bold part below

For F(x) F = 2x **when x ranges from 0 to 2, y ranges from 0 to 4**

or 
For for log functions **when x ranges from 0 to 1, y ranges from -inf to 0**

Comment: The *image* of a set $A$ under a map or function $f$ is usually denoted by $f(A)$.  For example, if $f(x) = 2x$, then $f([0,2]) = [0,4]$, and if $g(x) = \log(x)$, then $g((0,1]) = (-\infty,0]$.  The *range* of a function is the image of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one you write, $$F([0,2])=[0,4]$$

For the second one your write, $$ log((0,1))=(-\infty, 0)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say:

$$
\begin{aligned}
F(x) = 2x \qquad 0 \leq x \leq 2
\\ \therefore 0 \leq F(x) \leq 4
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, given a function $f:X\to Y$, the expressions $f(x),x\in X$ and $f(A),A\subset X$ are both meaningful expressions (in your case, the argument of your functions can be a real number or a *set* of real numbers). For example, the *range* of $f$ is defined as $f(X)$.

Thus, your first statement could be written $F\left([0,2]\right)=[0,4]$, your second, $g\left(]0,1]\right)=]-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Are you sure that *range of $f$* is $f(X)$?

Comment: @Sigur: The set $Y$ is the *codomain* of $f$. Although some people refer to the codomain as the *range*, I think it is generally more understood that the range, a subset of the codomain, is the image of the domain under the function, or $f(X)$. See the section on *image and pre-image* in the [Wikipedia article on functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)).

Comment: It is written there: *The range of a function is the set of the images of all elements in the domain. However, range is sometimes used as a synonym of codomain, generally in old textbooks.* Since I like and usually study old books, so... :)

Comment: Possibly we should avoid the word *range* altogether; with *domain*, *codomain* and *image*, it's redundant whichever convention we use...